# What can you do with native apps that you can't do with hybrid apps

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

With all the development in the Hybrid apps field the lasts couple of years (like [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/)) I was wondering: What can you do with native apps that you can't do with hybrid apps?

I know that there are some native features that are exclusive for a single operating system like [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html) on iOS.

Could someone provide a list of features that are exclusive to Android and iOS or maybe a Android vs iOS vs Ionic feature comparison?

Comment: I don't think you could specify a list. Cordova plugins are developped every day. Same for native features. What you should do (if you wanna develop an application), is look at what you can do with cordova (or other FW) and see if it's enough.

Comment: Are there features that are used in native applications often that you can't use in hybrid applications?

Comment: Hmmm, i don't think so. They are just different ways to do them. (At least, in my experience)

Comment: maybe persistence... I am not an expert in the hybrid apps world, but I would guess that they potentially have a hard time to include a database in their apps?!

Comment: IMO, everything is feasable in hybrid as all cordova plugins are, indeed, NATIVE scripts called. There is no limit of the capabilities of HYBRID apps

Comment: @nburk: databases are no issue, look at CouchDB and PouchDB

Comment: cool, didn't know that this was possible yet

Comment: even SQLite is available via cordova sqlite plugin

Comment: I believe Rich Text Editor is a issue in hybrid apps, you can't delete an image inside a contenteditable div using the softkeyboard backspace when the app is running in a real phone (no problems with emulators), that means you cannot develop 'Whatsapp' like chat apps that a message may contain images.

Comment: @aorfevre Everything is not possible. I wish it was (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ionic* is based on *Cordova*/*PhoneGap* which uses WebViews. I'll try to answer the more general part of *what can you not do with hybrid apps* or more exactly, example of things that seem impossible using a **WebView**:

- Replacing a **DOM element with a native element** is possible via [overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19372746/167897), but they cannot be attached to the DOM so if your element is animated via JavaScript or CSS it would lag behind (supposing you manually inform the overlay of its expected new position); scrolling should be possible to synchronize though.
- Cannot customize well for **accessibility**.
- cannot customize **text selection** / **long tap**.
- Another good (and frustrating) example is that on iOS you cannot **remove the accessory bar on the keyboard**. There are some plugins that can do it for certain versions of iOS, but it's super fragile and doesn't work 100% of the time.

As said, there are many things that are iOS-only or Android-only but those are almost always only because no one made the plugin for the other platform.